# how to match \% in impala sql

Tags: sql, impala

Impala Version: 5.12.2

I need to match string which contains \%， for example, a\%b. In impala shell，I use the following sql for test:

1. select 'a\\%b' like 'a\\\%b';
   The result is right:
   [sql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD7CZ.png)
2. select '\\%' like '\\\%'；
   I expected the result to be true, but actually I got false:
   [sql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noDgo.png)

I think both \ and % should be escaped in like, so I use '\\\%'. I don't known why the second sql doesn't work, could anyone explain it?

By the way, if I need to match string which contains two slash， for example a\b\c， I tried the flowing sql:

select  'a\\b\\c' like '%\\%\\%';

but the result is false:
[sql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ezcf.png)

Here，the % is used as wildcard, so I don't escape it. could anyone give a right sql?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The first result that you are listing does not match with your query, it should be True. Your second query is wrong, you need to escape the backlash as this `\\\\`

This query should do the job

```
select 'a\\b\\c' like '%\\\\%\\\\%';
```

Anyway I would recommend use regex

```
select regexp_like('a\\b\\c','(.*?)\\\\{1}(.*?)\\\\{1}(.*?)'); -- true
select regexp_like('a\\bc','(.*?)\\\\{1}(.*?)\\\\{1}(.*?)'); -- false
select regexp_like('a\\\\','(.*?)\\\\{1}(.*?)\\\\{1}(.*?)'); -- true
select regexp_like('\\\\','(.*?)\\\\{1}(.*?)\\\\{1}(.*?)'); -- true
select regexp_like('\\b\\c','(.*?)\\\\{1}(.*?)\\\\{1}(.*?)'); -- true
select regexp_like('ab\\','(.*?)\\\\{1}(.*?)\\\\{1}(.*?)'); -- false
```